Running my google fonts using widget test separately works, but fails when ran together
I have the following tests. They both pass if I run them separately. But if I run the together at once the second test fails because isEnabled == true. Upon further inspection it looks like it never gets to the line where isEnabled is set to true because it seems to keep hanging on await GoogleFonts.pendingFonts(); in the onEdit. But the test does end. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?
// Flutter imports:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Package imports:
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  setUpAll(() async {
    GoogleFonts.config.allowRuntimeFetching = false;
  });

  testWidgets('should load', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    //Act
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: SpecialTextWidget(
          shouldEdit: false,
        ),
      ),
    );

    //Assert
    final textWidgetFinder = find.byType(SpecialTextWidget);
    final loadedState = tester.state(textWidgetFinder) as SpecialTextWidgetState;
    expect(textWidgetFinder, findsOneWidget);
    expect(loadedState.isEnabled, true);
  });

  testWidgets('should handle edits', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    //Act
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: SpecialTextWidget(
          shouldEdit: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
    await tester.pump();

    //Assert
    final textWidgetFinder = find.byType(SpecialTextWidget);
    final editedState = tester.state(textWidgetFinder) as SpecialTextWidgetState;
    expect(textWidgetFinder, findsOneWidget);
    expect(editedState.isEnabled, false);
  });
}

class SpecialTextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool _shouldEdit;

  const SpecialTextWidget({
    super.key,
    bool shouldEdit = false,
  }) : _shouldEdit = shouldEdit;

  @override
  State<SpecialTextWidget> createState() => SpecialTextWidgetState();
}

class SpecialTextWidgetState extends State<SpecialTextWidget> {
  late bool _isInitialized;
  late bool _isEnabled;
  String? _data;
  TextStyle? _style;

  @visibleForTesting
  bool get isEnabled => _isEnabled;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isInitialized = false;
    _isEnabled = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (!_isInitialized) {
      initialize();
      _isInitialized = true;
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    await onLoad(
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      fontSize: 14.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
      color: Colors.black,
      isEnabled: true,
      data: 'Hello',
    );
    if (widget._shouldEdit) {
      await onEdit(
        fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
        fontSize: 16.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        color: Colors.white,
        isEnabled: false,
        data: 'Hello World',
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> onLoad({
    required String fontFamily,
    required double fontSize,
    required FontWeight fontWeight,
    required FontStyle fontStyle,
    required Color color,
    required bool isEnabled,
    required String data,
  }) async {
    final textStyle = GoogleFonts.getFont(
      fontFamily,
      fontSize: fontSize,
      fontWeight: fontWeight,
      fontStyle: fontStyle,
      color: color,
    );
    await GoogleFonts.pendingFonts();
    setState(() {
      _isEnabled = isEnabled;
      _data = data;
      _style = textStyle;
    });
  }

  Future<void> onEdit({
    required String fontFamily,
    required double fontSize,
    required FontWeight fontWeight,
    required FontStyle fontStyle,
    required Color color,
    required bool isEnabled,
    required String data,
  }) async {
    var updatedStyle = _style;
    updatedStyle = GoogleFonts.getFont(
      fontFamily,
      fontSize: fontSize,
      fontWeight: fontWeight,
      fontStyle: fontStyle,
      color: color,
    );
    await GoogleFonts.pendingFonts();
    setState(() {
      _isEnabled = isEnabled;
      _data = data;
      _style = updatedStyle;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_isEnabled) {
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    }

    return Text(
      _data!,
      style: _style,
    );
  }
}


Thanks for great reproduction example!
I think that your problem somehow connected with async nature of your initialisation code. "Somehow" – because I can not thoroughly describe exact reason. But I will show you code example which works and describes steps I did to reach that result.
So, since you call async function from initState(), you should wrap pumpWidget in runAsync method of tester. It's needed because simple pump will not work with such complex code. From docs:

Runs a [callback] that performs real asynchronous work.
This is intended for callers who need to call asynchronous methods where > the methods spawn isolates or OS threads and thus cannot be executed > synchronously by calling [pump].

As far as I can see, there is not new Isolates spawned in code of GoogleFonts. But, I think this is applicable for any async work too.
testWidgets('should handle edits', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.runAsync(() async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: SpecialTextWidget(
            shouldEdit: true,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
// ...other code...

Next, in your second test (should handle edits) there are several setState methods, and I think it's main clue to solving this problem.
We need somehow to pump all scheduled frames – that's pumpAndSettle made for. Doc comments of this method says that this method will wait for all animations to be completed, but I think it's also works with Future's created inside initialize.
So, I think final code should look like this:
testWidgets('should handle edits', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.runAsync(() async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: SpecialTextWidget(
            shouldEdit: true,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    // Run pumpAndSettle inside runAsync()
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  }
// ...other code...

More than that, I think that this approach should be used with both (or more) of your tests, because each of them has async work and setState inside that.
With that code, I was able to have both tests running successfully, either sequentially or running separately.

Hi @Sameri11, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately running this exact code yields the same error when running but tests at the same time.

did you wrapped pumpWidget in tester.runAsync in both tests? asking because I encounter same behaviour as you when only second (should handle edits) test wrapped. With debug prints I found out, that in that case onEdit never called, but it should in second test. I believe, that some global state (since GoogleFonts is singleton) is messed up when we are not doing actual async work.

Aah you are right putting the runAsync in both tests does seem to work. How strange. It does fix my issue so I'll give you the points, but I'll leave the question unanswered for now as I'm looking for the exact reason why this happens inside of Google Fonts. So I can request to have it fixed if it turns out to be problematic.

Yeah, I would also really like to know the exact reason
